# spring + jersey MediaType.APPLICATION_XML error

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jersey

i am trying to write a web service using Sprig + jersey here is my code:

```
package orgProfiles.webserviceJersey;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import orgProfiles.model.Registration;
import orgProfiles.repository.RegisterUserRepository;

@Path("mytest")
@Component
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private RegisterUserRepository registerUserRepository;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Registration> hitest() {
        return registerUserRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

repository:

```
package orgProfiles.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import orgProfiles.model.Registration;
@Repository("registerUserRepository")
public interface RegisterUserRepository extends JpaRepository<Registration,Long>{
    @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.name=:companyname")
    Registration findByCompanyname(@Param("companyname")String companyname);

//    @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.place like %:place%")
    List<Registration> findByPlaceContaining(String place);

//    @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.name like %:name%")
    List<Registration> findByNameContaining( String name);

//  @Query("Select c from Registration c where c.type like :type")
    List<Registration> findByTypeContaining(String type);

    List<Registration> findByTypeAndPlace(String type, String place);

    List<Registration> findByNameAndPlace(String name, String place);
}
```

Model:

```
package orgProfiles.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
@Entity
public class Registration {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String description;
    private String type;
    private String place;
    @Column(name="address", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String address;

    private String website;
    private double latitude;
    private Long phoneNum;
    private double longitude;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")  
    private LoginCredentials loginCredentials;
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    public LoginCredentials getLoginCredentials() {
        return loginCredentials;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Long getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum;
    }
    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLoginCredentials(LoginCredentials loginCredentials) {
        this.loginCredentials = loginCredentials;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setPhoneNum(Long phoneNum) {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }
    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }


}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.profiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>orgProfiles</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>orgProfiles Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

              <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Apache Commons IO -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>orgProfiles</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

When i try to access the service (http:// l o c alhost:8080/orgProfiles/ws/mytest) it end up with a HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error error . how can i mark my entity as @XmlRootElement? when i put that annotation it says XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type. when i change mediatype to  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON its work fine . Can i add JAXB dependency to get the @XMlRootElement annotation ?  Thanks in advanced

Comment: JAXB is included in JDK6 so i have to use 6 or higher

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jersey-json dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```